# How can I be more specific with .slideToggle?

Tags: jquery

*Terrible title, but I had trouble naming my problem.*

I'm trying to make a few boxes, which all—with the click of a button—will `.slideToggle()` and show a bunch of information. My problem is that each box should have its own button, because as it's coded right now, only one of the descriptions expands and collapses, no matter what button I click.

I have written the following jQuery-code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sponsor-description').hide();

    $('#sponsor .expand').click(function() {
         $('#sponsor-description').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

You can try it out for yourself at the website (click the orange "Expand"-button): http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/sponsors/.

How would I make so that when I click one of the "Expand"-buttons, the corresponding description slides down? I imagine `$(this)` could be helpful in some way, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: How does `#sponsor .expand` relate to `#sponsor-description`? With what you currently have, i'd guess you're using duplicate ID's (which is bad if you didn't already know)

Comment: @KevinB I want to make it automatic through WordPress. Currently each line is a post, so if I assign a unique ID to the class, I'm not sure how I would make it automatic in the future, when more sponsors have to be added. Do you have a proposal?

Comment: I do not because i can't see what you currently have. If you have duplicate ID's, fix that first. Duplicate ID's are invalid and cannot work.

Comment: @KevinB All sponsor posts are now unique, because of `div id="%post-id%"`. But how can I make this automatic through jQuery?

Comment: Give that div a class, next, where is .expand in relation to that div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#sponsor-description is an id. You are really abusing id's. They must be unique for each element. I suggest either using a unique id or using better selectors off of css classes.

Right now you are using sponsor-description as the id for every description element that's why your code fails.

I don't know Wordpress but if you can change all those id attributes to be classes you will be golden. Assuming you can change them your code will be:

```
$('.sponsor .expand').click(function() {
     $(this).parents('.sponsor').children('.sponsor-description').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: It should be automatic. Every line is a post written through WordPress.

Comment: I have now changed most of them to classes, but if I were to create unique ID's for each of the post-classes, I can't see how it would remain automatic, whenever I post a new sponsor post.

Comment: sorry i updated my answer. i just ran the code on your site and it seems to work.